# publishing int variable

Tags: ros, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I want to publish a variable, called targetIdx (type int), but I always get an error message

That's an extract of my publisher:

```
std_msgs::Int32 targetIdx;
targetIdx.data = targetIdx;
Sensor_Target_Nr_pub.publish(targetIdx);
ROS_INFO("Sensor Target Nr: %d", targetIdx.data);
```

That's the error message:

```
cannot convert ‘std_msgs::Int32’ to ‘std_msgs::Int32_<std::allocator<void> >::_data_type {aka int}’ in assignment
         targetIdx.data = targetIdx;
```

How can I solve the problem?

Thanks

I have declared the variable targetIdx as type int in the beginning of my program.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254562/publishing-int-variable/) by [fafa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29345/fafa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-02-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> std_msgs::Int32 targetIdx;
> ```

So `targetIdx` is declared to be of type `std_msgs::Int32` here ..

```
targetIdx.data = targetIdx;
```

.. and here you assign the just instantiated msg to its own `data` member.

That is not going to work.

Could it be that you are shadowing your `int targetIdx` with the newly created `std_msgs::Int32 targetIdx`?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fafa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29345/fafa/) on 2017-02-13**:
Sorry I'm new to programming and ROS...could you please give me an example how to publish an int variable

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-13**:
This is a C++ issue really, not a ROS issue.

You are creating a two variables with the same name. The compiler will only 'remember' the one that you created last. In this case that is the `std_msgs::Int32` one, not the `int`.

**Comment by [fafa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29345/fafa/) on 2017-02-13**:
Ok. The targetIdx variable is delivered by a sensor. So how can I easily publish this delivered variable?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-15**:
Just give your `std_msgs::Int32` instance a different name. Then everyhing should start working (provided you have the rest correctly implemented).